# How to theme an element of an array?

Tags: drupal

I have this array in a Drupal 7 installation, it outupts the term list that belongs to a specific vocabulary id:

```
<?php print render($content['taxonomy_vocabulary_3']); ?>
```

Now, what this does it outputs the result in a list, I would like to output it in a comma separated line.

Now, I suppose that I could do that with a foreach statement?

I´ve tried this, after [reading the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7), but it outputted nothing:

```
foreach($taxonomy_vocabulary_3 as $id=>$tag) {
echo "$tag, " ;
}
```

I´ve looked into what the Devel module told me about that array, and it showed me this:

```
taxonomy_vocabulary_3 (Array, 1 element)
    und (Array, 2 elements)
        0 (Array, 1 element)
            tid (String, 3 characters ) 141
        1 (Array, 1 element)
            tid (String, 3 characters ) 320
```

But as you can see it shows the term id in each case, and not the term name...

What do you suggest? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the term and then print it's title.

```
foreach($vocabulary as $tid) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  // print whatever you want from this object.
  print $term->title . ', '; 
}
```

[taxonomy_term_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7)

Answer (score 2):

What you got is a build array - so that means that

```
$content['taxonomy_vocabulary_3']['#theme']
```

will be the theme function used to render the vocabulary. If you want to change the output you have two good solutions.

- override the standard theme function in your theme - this will alter the output of all the calls to that theme function - in this case how all vocabularies is rendered.
- Change the `#theme` value to a theme function of your liking - this could be a custom theme function you define in your theme.

For help on how to render the terms, you can take a look at how the original theme function is implemented - you can look it up at the [Drupal API documentation](http://api.drupal.org).

Comment: THANKS FOR THE INSIGHT!! But how do you actually theme an item? I´m quite newbie in Drupal 7 and some stuff isn´t working the way it used to...